# Custom directive not resolving $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive but its not resolving the $scope variable filterValue, if I replace that with the actual value code is working fine,

Not Working :-

```
<tableau-viz 
height="'500px'" url="'https://public.tableau.com/views/USMassShooting2013-2015TrendsPerState/Story1?:embed=y'" filters={{filterValue}}> </tableau-viz>
```

Working :-

```
<tableau-viz height="'500px'" url="'https://public.tableau.com/views/USMassShooting2013-2015TrendsPerState/Story1?:embed=y'" filters="{'field1':['item1', 'item2'], 'dateField':{'min':startDate, 'max':endDate}}"> </tableau-viz>
```

I have created a Jsfiddle for that, can you please take a look, https://jsfiddle.net/iakash/rdrgvn3r/39/

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parsed value in the directive with one-way binding using the {{}} syntax in the template, change the directive object:

filters: "=" to filters: "@"

If you want to pass the model and maintain two-way binding, remove you're {{}} in the template:

```
<tableau-viz height="'500px'" url="'https://public.tableau.com/views/USMassShooting2013-2015TrendsPerState/Story1?:embed=y'" filters="filterValue"> </tableau-viz>
```

Comment: Thanks @Eeks33 for the help, it does help :)

Comment: @Learner - no problemo, if it does work mark the answer as correct ;) cheers